# Google Speech API word offset timestamps are inaccurate

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have some audio files (25 GB) for which I want to provide a feature for the user to see the highlighted word synced to the audio as it's being played. I was looking to Google Speech API to transcribe the files and provide the data for the word offsets so I wouldn't have to manually do this. However, I've noticed that the offsets are inconsistently accurate even if the API is able to transcribe the audio properly and accurately (over 90% confidence per word).

What can affect the accuracy of these word timings? 
Some observations:

1. I created an audio file of "The quick brown fox jumped over the sleeping lazy dog." using Audacity as a 16-bit wave with sampling of 44100. The API transcribed properly but word timings are way off missing entire words completely.
2. I create a wave file from Audible (via mic) and the word offsets were quite accurate.
3. I tried a professionally recorded Arabic file and although the API transcribed accurately, the word timings were way off.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail regarding the 3 audios that you are feeding the API :  1) Is the encoding the same for all three audio samples? Are all of them supported? Info about supported encodings - https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding#audio-encodings 2) Can you provide the expected results vs the received output results for all 3 audio files? I want to see how off the output is. 3) Is the second recording made in English? 4) Have you tried only 1 Arabic recording?

Comment: I have the same issue: the word offsets for a Russian transcript are quite inaccurate. Another detail: I get the response as described in the documentation `response = client.recognize(config, audio_bytes)` but the values in `start_time.nanos` and `end_times.nanos` are very round numbers precise to 0.1 seconds, which is strange. By the way, I feed in wav audio sampled at 16000 Hz.

Comment: I have also tried getting the alignments/timing for af-ZA and ta-IN and both are terrible. Practically useless! This is a prime use case of a Speech API to find alignments. Can we have some answers or a roadmap at least, please. I am sure these timings must be available during your decoding stage so to pass them through correctly should not be a big things for a paid API service by Google.

Comment: I re-tested this on Google's own demo audio file (gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac) and using the Video Model which is supposed to be better. The timings/alignments are horrible and again practically useless!